# Firebase Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
<script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
  import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';

  // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    config
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  const database = getDatabase(app)
</script>
```

The Uncaught TypeError occurs in line 2. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this happens because firebase's newest version tools for developers for tools like *database*, *auth* , etc, are buggy. Install an older version of firebase. That will surely do the trick.
(I am guessing you are using NPM or Yarn to install them, so do something like `npm i firebase@5.10.0`)

Comment: How can I install it?

Comment: Well, so if you are using NPM, do 'npm uninstall firebase' in the command prompt, and then install it again with 'npm i firebase@5.10.0.' May I know if you are actually using NPM?

Comment: Also if you are just using vanilla js with no bundles and NPM or Yarn then of course it won't work because "firebase/database" is not defined. In that case, you would have to use src links.

Comment: The error turns into "Access to script at 'file:///C:/firebase/app' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted." What does this error mean?

Comment: Have you done what I have said above? Otherwise, the error shouldn't come...